# $N$ is a closed or open set?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the set of natural numbers and

it is asked to find the set of internal set, of external set and of boundary set.

The set of internal points is $E^i= \emptyset $,

the set of external points is $E^e= R-N $
and the boundary set $N$ itself.

In my opinion N is closed because the boundary is $N$ itself  and it is a part of $N$.
The solution in my book suggests the contrary.

Comment: What book, what exercise?

Comment: What is the topology?

Comment: The answer of the question depends on the topological space of which $N$ is considered as a subset. Is $N$ a subset of $R$? A subset of itself? Other?

Comment: @Hellen N is considered as a subset of R

Comment: Then it is a closed subset of $R$. To prove it it is enough to prove that its complement is open. To prove that let $x$ be any point in $R\setminus N$. Then the interval open $(x-[x+1/2]/2, x+[x+1/2]/2)\subset (R\setminus N)$. This proves that $N$ is closed. Therefore its exterior is $R\setminus N$. Its interior is empty because any open interval centered at an element of $N$ is going to contain elements from $R\setminus N$.